# Copy, Paste and delete row from one worksheet to another

Tags: excel, vba

please can someone help me?? I have been trying lots of different codes for weeks and it seems as though I am getting no where as I don't know what I am doing.

I have 5 worksheets. 
From worksheet1 I would like entire rows to be copied to worksheet5 if column G says "Discharged"
I would like the row that is copied from worksheet 1 to be deleted after it is copied 
If possible can the new copied row in worksheet5 go to the next available blank row

This is the same for all worksheets 1-4, eventually data rows will end up on worksheet5 when column G states "Discharged"

I had a working code which worked well but as soon as I had it applied to all 4 worksheets it would intermittently freeze, is this just because I have too many macros applied?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Without seeing your code it's impossible to comment on it. Please add your code to your question. Bear in mind that "is this just because I have too many macros applied?" permits a yes/no answer that may not satisfy you. Perhaps, once you post your code you can also rephrase your question to permit a useful answer.

Comment: How may rows on the sheets. more than 10,000 ?

Comment: Please make sure to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question accordingly. Writing such vague questions will get you nowhere. Also remember that asking for opinions on this site will get your question closed for offtopic in no time. I would start by creating a smaller example to show here (both the code and the data) if you can't/don't want to share the entire thing.